# Crystal reports lines not showing

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report for an invoice that is formatted with some horizontal and vertical lines. The vertical lines cut across a number of group and detail sections. Crystal reports is version 13, and I am using it in the designer in Visual Studio 2013.

I have two problems

1) The vertical lines only extend to the beginning of the first detail section on the first page. On subsequent pages they display all the way down the screen.

2) For the second and last row of one of my groups, the vertical lines don't display at all.

I have tried removing the lines and re-adding them, and this has made no difference. I have also tried changing ExtendToBottomOfSection to true for the lines, but this doesn't seem to make any difference. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you r able , then upload image to understand more better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing with lines and boxes in Crystal Reports is the section/area they start in and the section/area they end in. These areas always go in a specific order: Report Header, Page Header, Group Headers, Details, Group Footers, Report Footer, Page Footer.

Depending on the height of the areas, some sections may be bumped to the next page. Most issues I see with lines and boxes are due to them not starting/ending in the right section to give the desired effect on every page, even pages where some sections may be omitted.

If you want lines to span the whole page, they should start at the top of the Page Header area and end in the bottom of the Page Footer.

**What I think you're looking for** is a slight variation on this (I'm guessing based on your problem description): to run the line down the entire page, but not actually have it appear in the page header/footer.  In this case, you will want the line to start at the **bottom** of the page header, and end at the **top** of the page footer. This will give the effect of the line covering the page (but not the header/footer), regardless of how many records appear on the page.

These properties are easiest to control from Design view (where it's easier to distinguish section boundaries), or from the properties dialog (where you can make the top/bottom values exact).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I think you are on to something. My lines (this is a report that I have inherited) start in a group header and end on a detail section. I have tried adding a line that starts in the same group header and finishes in the group footer, and that displays without any gaps. I will attempt to reformat using this model.